# Integer.decode(String s)

Tags: java

```
class Test{

    public static void main(String Args[]){

        Integer x;
        x = Integer.decode("0b111");
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work with the prefix 0 for binary and for octal with the prefix 0.
What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @RohitJain: No it doesn't. That's hex.

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String))

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Oh Crap. It's just `0`. I got wrong there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`Integer.decode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29), I see no indication that binary *should* work. Octal should work though, with a prefix of just 0:

```
System.out.println(Integer.decode("010")); // Prints 8
```

You could handle a binary indicator of "0b" like this:

```
int value = text.toLowerCase().startsWith("0b") ? Integer.parseInt(text.substring(2), 2)
                                  : Integer.decode(text);
```

Complete sample code showing binary, octal, decimal and hex representations of 15:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] strings = { "0b1111", "017", "15", "0xf" };
        for (String string : strings) {
            System.out.println(decode(string)); // 15 every time
        }
    }

    private static int decode(String text) {
        return text.toLowerCase().startsWith("0b") ? Integer.parseInt(text.substring(2), 2)
                                     : Integer.decode(text);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Logged it as a RFE about a year ago. Maybe it will be fixed one day. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Integer.decode cannot parse binary, see API. But octal work fine, example:

```
int i = Integer.decode("011");
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 7, you can use [binary literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html) directly in your code. However, note that these are of type `byte`, `short`, `int` or `long` (and *not* `String`).

```
int x = 0b111;
```