# Searching only for a zero in Java with nothing preceding it or following it

Tags: java, string

I am working on a program that takes in 2 numbers and either adds, subtracts, multiplies, or divides them. The numbers can either be binary, hexadecimal, octal, or decimal numbers. In order for a user of the program to enter a binary number they must enter a "0b" in front of it. They would need to enter a "0" in front of the octal numbers, "0x" for hexadecimal, and just the number for a decimal number. The original number that is read in is a String then the method below converts it to an int or a double. I am trying to find out a solution if a user enters in a "0" for the number itself. Is there a way to see if the users input is only a 0 with nothing preceding it or following it? Here is my method I am working with. Any help would be awesome!

```
public double evaluate()
{
    int sign = getSign();//makes number positive or negative

    if (getOperand().startsWith("0"))// this is where i am trying to see if the number is just 0
    {
        return 0 * sign;
    }

    else if (getOperand().startsWith("0x"))
    {
        String op = getOperand().substring(2);
        return Integer.parseInt(op, 16)*sign;
    }

    else if (getOperand().startsWith("0b"))
    {
        String op = getOperand().substring(2);
        return Integer.parseInt(op, 2)*sign;
    }

    else if (getOperand().startsWith("0"))
    {
        String op = getOperand().substring(1);
        return Integer.parseInt(op, 8)*sign;
    }

    else
    {
        String op = getOperand();
        return (Double.parseDouble(op)) * sign;
    }
```

Comment: You should take a look at `Integer.decode`, which handles a few of your cases (not the binary, though.) see @JonSkeet's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549597/integer-decodestring-s

Comment: also, you are apparently parsing a double in last resort, but the double could be `0.32`, in which case it does start with a 0, but is not octal int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making more work for yourself than you need.  Just parse plain "0" as an octal number -- the result is still 0.  No need to remove the leading zero.

That is,

```
// ...
else if (getOperand().startsWith("0"))
    {
        String op = getOperand();
        return Integer.parseInt(op, 8)*sign;
    }
// ...
```

Comment: in the current status, it would actually crash, because the part that handles the octal removes the leading 0, meaning `0` will result in `""` being parsed, which crashes.

Comment: Yes.  That's why I said "no need to remove the leading zero" and presented example code that demonstrates it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
getOperand().equals("0")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the string is actually a zero with nothing before or after, you want equality.

```
getOperand().equals("0")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check

```
if (getOperand().equals("0"))
```

However, you have another problem - your code will throw exceptions for invalid inputs. If the user enters just the prefix "0b" or "0x", your substring call would throw an exception. You must verify that there's at least one character following the prefix. It will also throw an exception if the substring can't be parsed as a number of the requested base.